# springboot automatically ignoring unknown json properties

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, gradle, jackson

Using springboot with gradle i am getting 10 parameters from an api but my class is catching only 2 paramaters.How during json mapping to my class it is automatically ignoring unknown properties.I have not specified @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) on top of my class.Is there any global config for object mapper.If yes then with what name/annotation.I am sending request like below-:

```
ExplicitLoadResponse explicitLoadResponse = HttpSender
                .send(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "bookNextLoad", url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, ExplicitLoadResponse.class,false);
```

Pojo is -:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
@Data
public class ExplicitLoadResponse {
    Long bookNextLoadId;
}
```

Comment: Shown your pojo and requestEntity code

Comment: @kann i have added the response pojo